# Force Ethernet physical link state in Linux

Tags: linux, ethernet

Is there a generic way to force Ethernet physical link state from Linux userspace? I know that at least the Intel e1000 driver puts the PHY to powerdown when the interface is deconfigured with

```
ifconfig eth0 down
```

This makes the physical link go down (if wake-on-lan isn't enabled).

However, other Ethernet chips such as those from Realtek don't seem to modify their physical link states when ifconfig is used.

Using mii-tool to restart autonegotiation puts the link down temporarily, but can you force it down completely or can you directly write PHY registers through some interface to accomplish the same?

Comment: I honestly do not know :) Last time I tried to manage the link states, I also checked the "modern" alternative `ip` like `ip link set eth1 down`, maybe it is worth trying?

Comment: Other people seem to have the same problem, looks like there is no common/straightforward solution, see also first answer here: [ServerFault: How to physically shut off network interface in Linux (Redhat/Centos)](https://serverfault.com/questions/801665/how-to-physically-shut-off-network-interface-in-linux-redhat-centos)

Answer (score 1):

Found this in the readme file of an r8125 realtek driver installation folder:

Force Link Status>

```
1. Force the link status when insert the driver.

   If the user is in the path ~/r8125, the link status can be forced
   to one of the 5 modes as following command.

    # insmod ./src/r8125.ko speed=SPEED_MODE duplex=DUPLEX_MODE autoneg=NWAY_OPTION

    ,where
        SPEED_MODE  = 1000  for 1000Mbps
                = 100   for 100Mbps
                = 10    for 10Mbps
        DUPLEX_MODE = 0 for half-duplex
                = 1 for full-duplex
        NWAY_OPTION = 0 for auto-negotiation off (true force)
                = 1 for auto-negotiation on (nway force)
    For example:

        # insmod ./src/r8125.ko speed=100 duplex=0 autoneg=1

    will force PHY to operate in 100Mpbs Half-duplex(nway force).

2. Force the link status by using ethtool.
    a. Insert the driver first.
    b. Make sure that ethtool exists in /sbin.
    c. Force the link status as the following command.

        # ethtool -s ethX speed SPEED_MODE duplex DUPLEX_MODE autoneg NWAY_OPTION

        ,where
            SPEED_MODE  = 1000  for 1000Mbps
                    = 100   for 100Mbps
                    = 10    for 10Mbps
            DUPLEX_MODE = half  for half-duplex
                    = full  for full-duplex
            NWAY_OPTION = off   for auto-negotiation off (true force)
                    = on    for auto-negotiation on (nway force)

    For example:

        # ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg on

    will force PHY to operate in 100Mpbs Full-duplex(nway force).
```

Comment: That only affects speed, duplexity, and autonegotiation. No effect on physical link up/down.